# Adding a string to a row at a JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am using a PHP to obtain a JSON array to be retrieved by an android app.

One of the fields is called `strImagen`, this field stores a file name.

I would need to add the URL path to the file name as part of the row to be JSON encoded.

Example:

If

```
$row['strImagen'] = '123456789.png'
```

it should be

```
htttp://myserverURL/images/123456789.png
```

This is the PHP part of code where I am creating the JSON array:

```
// query the application data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbempresas";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

// an array to save the application data
$rows = array();

// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row; 
}

// close the database connection
mysqli_close($con);

// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode($rows);
```

I need your help to do this... thank you

Comment: So have you made any attempt to do this at all?  You are after all talking about just basic string concatenation.

Comment: @MikeBrant, thank you , but I think this is more complicated that basic string concatenation, at least for me PHP level, I am sure you are an expert but I am not. Thank you in any case.

Comment: @msvasco It is not more complicated than basic string concatenation. See answer from AbraCadaver below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_walk` for that.. Add the below code after the end of your `while` loop.

```
array_walk($row,function (&$v){ $v['strImagen']='http://myserverURL/images/'.$v['strImagen'];});
```

Comment: It works, but I getting weird characters executing the PHP directly on the browser, I guess it will look fine at the app. Thank you again.

Comment: If not, please let know , will be glad to look on to the issue ;)

Comment: I am sure that it will be fine at the app, if not I will tell you. Thank you.

Comment: it works, thank you for your time, effort and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in the loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $row['strImagen'] = "htttp://myserverURL/images/{$row['strImagen']}";
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: your proposal is not working, the JSON output is the same with and without your code line.

Comment: may it is a browser issue, don't worry, i guess it is fine as you say. Thank you

Comment: it works, thank you for your time and effort.